# Hibernate updating Null Values to dynamic updatable table

Tags: java, hibernate

Here is the problem I am facing.

I have a table with a not-null field CREATE_DATE. I dont want to update this particular column when any update is done in this table. So I gave

```
dynamic-insert="true" dynamic-update="true"
```

in the table hbm.xml. 
So the problem is I am getting error like trying to update null to a not-null field even though i am not modifying that object. I am pasting the code here.

```
if (userDO.getUserId() != null) {
                if(SessionManager.getInstance().currentSession() != null){
                    getSession().evict(userDO);
                    getSession().clear();
                }
                getSession().update(userDO);
                //getSession().saveOrUpdate(userDO);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your domain class above the field you don't want to store as NULL set:

```
@Column (nullable = false)
```

Comment: What if we are not updating the not-null fields as null? Thats what i am talking about. I do not want to update that purticular column.